# Can't publish from a thread in paho python mqtt

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt, paho

I'm using paho-mqtt library to run a python based mqtt client.
I'm not being able to publish message from a separate thread as per the following code

```
cb_client = mqtt.Client(
    client_id = "timerScript",
    userdata = [db,conf],
    clean_session = True,
    protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311
)

cb_client.username_pw_set(bc['username'], bc['password'])
userdata = [db,conf]
cb_client.connect(host=bc['host'], port=int(bc['port']))
handle_trigger(cb_client, userdata,trigger) 
cb_client.loop_forever()

def handle_trigger(cbClient,userdata,trigger):
    route = route[0][0]
    cbClient.publish("test","from handler") << this is working
    t = threading.Thread(target=execute_trigger, args=[cbClient, userdata, trigger,route])
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return

def execute_trigger(cbClient,userdata,trigger,route):
   print("Executing trigger {}".format(trigger))
   cbClient.publish("test","from thread") # <<this publish in thread is not working
```

Comment: No error messages, not hint as to what code is doing what and if any of it is executed (the print for instance).

Comment: @Torxed print in the line above is working fine but publish is neither throwing any error and nor working

Comment: @Torxed publish in handler is also working

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Add another print after `publish()`, does that get executed?

Comment: @Torxed i have a dummy client running on mqtt spy which is connected to the same server.
publish done in the handler is received in the mqtt spy.
In execute_trigger method - print before publish works fine, print after the publish works fine, but I dont  get the publish in execute trigger in mqtt spy and the code is not even throwing any error

Comment: @Torxed another interesting thing.I tried keeping an on_connect callback, the callback was triggered perfectly, but I cant even publish from within the on_connect callback. Same thing is happening, print after and before on_connect is working but publish is not received in mqtt-spy and nor is throwing any error

Comment: It sounds like you have a issue with how you're sending messages rather than messages not being published. I have no idea what the format and/or how messages are meant to be correctly published. But it sure sounds like a issue with the way you're publishing rather than the code itself.

Comment: HI! 
Have you solved this problem?